# Access VBA recordset insert field error happening

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba

I have an Access application that queries a directory on the network and links to flat csv files that are output from a manufacturing machine controller. I create select query linked to each csv file and loop the records and insert them to another table using my ImportData function:

```
Public Function ImportData(strPath As String, strFile As String, strTableName As String, strSheetVar As String) As Boolean
'On Error Resume Next
Dim csvTable As String
Dim strName2, strName3 As String

Dim origRS As DAO.Recordset
Dim destRS As DAO.Recordset
sql = "Select * FROM [Text;;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=" & strPath & "].[" & strFile & "]"

Set origRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
Set destRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTableName)

    origRS.MoveFirst

    Do Until origRS.EOF
        destRS.AddNew
        destRS("[Date]") = CDate(origRS("[Date]"))
        destRS("[Time]") = CDate(origRS("[Time]"))
        destRS("[DateTimeKey]") = CDate(origRS("[Date]") & " " & origRS("[Time]"))
        destRS("[Shift End]") = origRS("[Shift End]")
        destRS("[Name21-1]") = Trim(CStr(origRS("[Name21-1]")))
        destRS("[StartTime1]") = origRS("[StartTime1]")
        destRS("[Name21-2]") = Trim(CStr(origRS("[Name21-2]")))
        destRS("[StartTime2]") = origRS("[StartTime2]")
        destRS("[Name21-3]") = Trim(CStr(origRS("[Name21-3]")))
        destRS("[StartTime3]") = origRS("[StartTime3]")
        destRS("[CNT]") = origRS("[CNT]")
        destRS("[Down Time]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Down Time]")))
        destRS("[Job #1]") = origRS("[Job #1]")
        destRS("[MR Time 1]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[MR Time 1]")))
        destRS("[Waste #1]") = origRS("[Waste #1]")
        destRS("[Count #1]") = origRS("[Count #1]")
        destRS("[Run Time 1]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Run Time 1]")))
        destRS("[Total Cnt 1]") = origRS("[Total Cnt 1]")
        destRS("[Total MR 1]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Total MR 1]")))
        destRS("[Job #2]") = origRS("[Job #2]")
        destRS("[MR Time 2]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[MR Time 2]")))
        destRS("[Waste #2]") = origRS("[Waste #2]")
        destRS("[Count #2]") = origRS("[Count #2]")
        destRS("[Run Time 2]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Run Time 2]")))
        destRS("[Total Cnt 2]") = origRS("[Total Cnt 2]")
        destRS("[Total MR 2]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Total MR 2]")))
        destRS("[Job #3]") = origRS("[Job #3]")
        destRS("[MR Time 3]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[MR Time 3]")))
        destRS("[Waste #3]") = origRS("[Waste #3]")
        destRS("[Count #3]") = origRS("[Count #3]")
        destRS("[Run Time 3]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Run Time 3]")))
        destRS("[Total Cnt 3]") = origRS("[Total Cnt 3]")
        destRS("[Total MR 3]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Total MR 3]")))
        destRS("[Job #4]") = origRS("[Job #4]")
        destRS("[MR Time 4]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[MR Time 4]")))
        destRS("[Waste #4]") = origRS("[Waste #4]")
        destRS("[Count #4]") = origRS("[Count #4]")
        destRS("[Run Time 4]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Run Time 4]")))
        destRS("[Total Cnt 4]") = origRS("[Total Cnt 4]")
        destRS("[Total MR 4]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Total MR 4]")))
        destRS("[Job #5]") = origRS("[Job #5]")
        destRS("[MR Time 5]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[MR Time 5]")))
        destRS("[Waste #5]") = origRS("[Waste #5]")
        destRS("[Count #5]") = origRS("[Count #5]")
        destRS("[Run Time 5]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Run Time 5]")))
        destRS("[Total Cnt 5]") = origRS("[Total Cnt 5]")
        destRS("[Total MR 5]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Total MR 5]")))
        destRS("[Job #6]") = origRS("[Job #6]")
        destRS("[MR Time 6]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[MR Time 6]")))
        destRS("[Waste #6]") = origRS("[Waste #6]")
        destRS("[Count #6]") = origRS("[Count #6]")
        destRS("[Run Time 6]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Run Time 6]")))
        destRS("[Total Cnt 6]") = origRS("[Total Cnt 6]")
        destRS("[Total MR 6]") = ConvertTimeToDecimal(CDate(origRS("[Total MR 6]")))
        destRS.Update
    origRS.MoveNext

    Loop


End Function
```

If I run the code and step through it, this line:

```
destRS("[Name21-1]") = Trim(CStr(origRS("[Name21-1]")))
```

is always successful.

If I get to this line

```
destRS("[Name21-2]") = Trim(CStr(origRS("[Name21-2]")))
```

it will fail if there is a value, but work if there is not a value.

The values in these columns:
Name21-1
Name21-2
Name21-3
are identical values of someones last name. I cannot find a reason why this would fail at all.

I have attached a image of the file that would be processed using this code.
[image]
Please ask me for more detail if needed.

Comment: When the column is nullable, you need to check for DbNull.Value in your recordset before applying any data conversion functions

Comment: @T.S. I will give it a go when I go onsite again and report back.

Comment: @HansUp - I don't recall, but I will check back after going onsite.

Comment: I agree it is probably a 'Null' issue, but this is a good place to include an error trap. When the error hits, you can display which record is involved -- and the error number and description.